# Show recent activities from Yammer on intranet

Tags: yammer

I'm looking for a way to show Yammer recent user activities as e feed on an intranet application. I believe there is no RSS feed available? I looked at the REST API. But I was wondering if I can use the REST API to show these activities without the internet visitor having to sign in.

We would like to show these activities on the intranet of the company to get more people to use Yammer. So that is why we would like to show some activity to non-yammer-users.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create a Yammer app that is able to login and read content from your network to do this. The Yammer app will have an OAUTH token that authenticates it to Yammer to read the information.

More info on creating an app to do what you're explaining is available at: https://developer.yammer.com/introduction/. You would then use the REST API to program your app to display the information that you want.